# Solution to a given differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am stuck since yesterday to understand how to find the right solution to the differential equation as posted in the image below

[image]

Then, I tried to solve as shown below, but I am not able to reach a proper solution, but it seems like I am hitting a wall.

[image]

What could be the best way to reach a solution?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Why don't you use Laplace Transform ?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos : I will keep this in mind for future convsersations on stack exchange

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$e^{2t}\cdot 2u(t)=e^{2t}(x'(t)+2x(t))=(e^{2t}x(t))'.$$
Now integrate both sides with respect to $t$ over the interval $[0,T]$ for $T>0$ (the solution is identically zero for $T\leq 0$).
$$\int_0^T e^{2t}\cdot 2u(t)dt=e^{2T}x(T)-x(0).$$
Can you take it from here and find the solution $x(T)$?

P.S. It is a first order linear differential equation. As a general reference see  [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First-order_equation_with_variable_coefficients).

Comment: @MasoomKumar What do you mean? I edited my answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to write it using MathJax format and pressed enter. I am trying to move forward from the hint that you have provided

Comment: @MasoomKumar Please try again.

Comment: How to we integrate $u(t)$, before applying limits of definite integral to it ?

Comment: $u(t)=1$  for $t>0$ so just integrate, $\int_0^T e^{2t}\cdot 2dt$

Answer (score 0):

Integrating factor works here:  multiply through by $I=e^{\int2\operatorname dt}=e^{2t}$.

Get $e^{2t}x'(t)=-2e^{2t}x(t)+2e^{2t}u(t)\implies (e^{2t}x(t))'=2e^{2t}u(t)\implies e^{2t}x(t)=2\int e^{2t}u(t)\operatorname dt$.

But $2\int e^{2t}u(t)=e^{2t}+C\,,\forall t\gt0$.

Thus $x(t)=e^{-2t}(e^{2t}+C)=1+Ce^{-2t}$.

And $0=x(0)=1+C\implies C=-1$.

So $\boxed{x(t)=1-e^{-2t}\,,\forall t\gt0}$.

Comment: isn't the condition $x(0) = 0$ only applicable for t=0? Here you have derived $x(t)$ for $t>0$ , and then used $x(t=0)$ to find the constant of integration

Comment: Yes, but the condition $x(0)=0$ enables us to find $C$.  Remember $x$ is continuous.   So $C+1=\lim_{t\to0}x(t)=x(0)=0$.